# Как вывести случайную новость из базы

Tags: php, html, mysql, smarty

Помогите реализовать вывод новости таким образом чтобы каждый раз при перезагрузке выводилась одна любая новость из базы пример кода

**php**

```
require_once ROOT_PATH.'/market/apps/qnews/models/qnews.class.php';
$qnews = new qnews();
$qnews = $qnews->getAll(0, 10, "`visible` = 'true'");
abr('qnews', $qnews);
```

**html**

```
   {if $qnews}
        {foreach from=$qnews item=i name=foo} 
           $i.name}
           {$i.description}
        {/foreach}
    {/if}
```

**php class**

```
/*
 * GET FUNCTIONS
 */
public function getAll($start=0, $limit=0, $where='') {
    global $mysql, $language;

    $limitQuery = '';
    if($limit!=0) {
        $limitQuery = " LIMIT $start,$limit ";
    }

    if($where!='') {
        $where = "WHERE ".$where;
    }

    $mysql->query("
        SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *
        FROM `qnews`
        $where
        ORDER BY `order_index` ASC
        $limitQuery
    ", __FUNCTION__ );

    if($mysql->num_rows() == 0) {
        return array();
    }

    $return = array();
    while($d = $mysql->fetch_array()) {
        $return[$d['id']] = $d;
    }

    $this->foundRows = $mysql->getFoundRows();

    return $return;
}

public function get($id) {
    global $mysql;

    $mysql->query("
        SELECT *
        FROM `qnews`
        WHERE `id` = '".intval($id)."'
    ", __FUNCTION__ );

    if($mysql->num_rows() == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    return $mysql->fetch_array();


}
```

**SQL Dump**

```
--
-- Структура таблицы `qnews`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `qnews` (
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `description` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `bgcolor` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `fontcolor` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `url` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `photo` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `visible` enum('true','false') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'true',
  `order_index` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `qnews`
--

INSERT INTO `qnews` (`id`, `name`, `description`, `bgcolor`, `fontcolor`, `url`, `photo`, `visible`, `order_index`) VALUES
(1, '', '','','', '', '', 'true', 1),
(2, '', '','','', '', '', 'true', 2);
```

Comment: а "случайность" на каком этапе нужна? При получении из базы: `select...order by rand() limit 1`, при выводе: `array_rand($qnews)`

Comment: $qnews = array_rand($qnews, 5); так побывал  не получилось

Comment: хотя насчет `order by rand()` не уверен, возможно будет лучше выбрать сначала максимальный id записи, сгенерировать случайное число от 0 до максимального id и выбрать первую запись, id которой больше полученного случайного числа.

Comment: Еще такой вариант $qnews = $qnews->getAll(0, 10, "`visible` = 'true' AND `id` ", 'RAND()'); тоже не работает может я что упустил не силен в php

Comment: @evanto, вместо `array_rand` можно использовать [`shuffle`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.shuffle.php)

Comment: при выводе: array_rand($qnews) было бы удобнее есть какие варианты.

Comment: `array_rand($qnews, 1)` ?)

Comment: не `SELECT order by rand() limit 1...`, а `select * from qnews order by rand() limit 1`

Comment: SELECT * FROM qnews ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 Реакции не какой

Comment: изначально там было так SELECT *

Comment: kshuffle($qnews); вот так помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выбираем максимальное значение `id`:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM `news`;
```

Стоит знать сколько всего новостей, дабы не увязнуть в бесконечном цикле:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `news`;
```

Можно запросы совместить. И результаты присваиваем `$maxID` и `$newsCount` соответственно. 
Генерируем случайные `id`, проверяя их на существование и на выбраны ли они уже:

```
//$newsCount - количество новостей
//$maxID - максимальный ID новости
$needCount = 5; //необходимо 5 случайных новостей
$news = array(); //массив случайных новостей
for ($i = 1; $i <= min($needCount, $newsCount); $i++) {
    do {
        $rand = mt_rand(1, $maxID);
    } while (in_array($rand, $news) AND !/*SELECT id FROM `news` WHERE id = $rand;*/);
    $news[] = $rand;
}
```

Функция `min` выберет минимальное значение, если мы хотим 5 случайных новостей, а их всего 3, то больше 3 выбрать не получится.

В `while` делаем выборки, чтобы узнать, существует ли новость, ведь мы можем ее и удалить, а авто-инкриминент пойдет дальше, `id` останется не занятым:

```
SELECT id FROM `news` WHERE id = $rand;
```